# Como acionar esta barra de progresso?

Tags: jquery, rolamento, progress-bar, jquery-animate

Comecei a estudar agora JavaScript e jQuery, e procurando como fazer uma barra de progresso vertical encontrei a função abaixo:

Funcionou perfeitamente como eu queria, porém eu gostaria de saber como posso fazer com que as barras sejam acionadas (comecem a carregar) apenas quando eu rolar o scroll e chegar na posição em que elas se encontram, que é bem no final da página.
Se alguém puder me ajudar agradeço imensamente!!!

```js
$(function(){
  $("#bars li .bar").each(function(key, bar){
    var percentage = $(this).data('percentage');
  $(this).animate({
    'height':percentage+'%'}, 2000);
  })
})
```

```css
#chart #bars {
   display: inline-block;
   padding: 0;
   margin: 0;
   padding-left: 45px;
   text-align: center;}

#chart #bars li {
   display: table-cell;
   width: 100px;
   height: 300px;
   margin: 0;
    color: gray;
   text-align: center;
   position: relative;}

#chart #bars li .bar {
  display: block;
  width: 70px;
  margin-left: 25px;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  position: absolute;  
  bottom: 0;}

.barra1{background: linear-gradient(#ffe1e6, #ff7b90);}
.barra2{background: linear-gradient(#aef0ee, #22bcb8);}
.barra3{background: linear-gradient(#fffcae, #fff962);}
.barra4{background: linear-gradient(#e1ffbe, #c4e59c);}
.barra5{background: linear-gradient(#e0c6ff, #bd9ce5);}

#chart #bars li span {
 position: absolute;
 bottom: -3em;
 left: 20px;
 line-height: 14px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <div id="chart" style="float: left;">
           <ul id="bars">
            <li><div data-percentage="80" class="bar barra1"></div><span>1</span></li>
            <li><div data-percentage="85" class="bar barra2"></div><span>2</span></li>
            <li><div data-percentage="90" class="bar barra3"></div><span>3</span></li>
            <li><div data-percentage="75" class="bar barra4"></div><span>4</span></li>
            <li><div data-percentage="70" class="bar barra5"></div><span>5</span></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pode usar este código, que fará a animação iniciar quando a `div #chart` aparecer ao menos a metade na tela:

```js
$(function(){
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        var el = $("#chart");
        var elTopo = el.offset().top;
        var elHeight = el.outerHeight();
        var scrlTopo = $(window).scrollTop();
        var altJanela = window.innerHeight; 
        var distance = elTopo-scrlTopo;
        if(distance <= altJanela-(elHeight/2)){
            $("#bars li .bar").each(function(key, bar){
                var percentage = $(this).data('percentage');
                $(this).animate({
                    'height':percentage+'%'
                }, 2000);
            });
        }
    });
})
```

```css
#chart #bars {
   display: inline-block;
   padding: 0;
   margin: 0;
   padding-left: 45px;
   text-align: center;}

#chart #bars li {
   display: table-cell;
   width: 100px;
   height: 300px;
   margin: 0;
    color: gray;
   text-align: center;
   position: relative;}

#chart #bars li .bar {
  display: block;
  width: 70px;
  margin-left: 25px;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  position: absolute;  
  bottom: 0;}

.barra1{background: linear-gradient(#ffe1e6, #ff7b90);}
.barra2{background: linear-gradient(#aef0ee, #22bcb8);}
.barra3{background: linear-gradient(#fffcae, #fff962);}
.barra4{background: linear-gradient(#e1ffbe, #c4e59c);}
.barra5{background: linear-gradient(#e0c6ff, #bd9ce5);}

#chart #bars li span {
 position: absolute;
 bottom: -3em;
 left: 20px;
 line-height: 14px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Role pra baixo
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
   <div id="chart" style="float: left;">
           <ul id="bars">
            <li><div data-percentage="80" class="bar barra1"></div><span>1</span></li>
            <li><div data-percentage="85" class="bar barra2"></div><span>2</span></li>
            <li><div data-percentage="90" class="bar barra3"></div><span>3</span></li>
            <li><div data-percentage="75" class="bar barra4"></div><span>4</span></li>
            <li><div data-percentage="70" class="bar barra5"></div><span>5</span></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
```